# How are WebAPI's implemented within google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

While execution and the call stack are left to the V8 I would like to know how the various WebAPI's are implemented within the chrome. Are they compiled C libraries that are made available to JavaScript or are they implemented in JavaScript them selves?

Comment: Every browser core is its own codebase with its own implementation of everything. On top of that, browsers that run on different OS/hardware combinations may need per-platform runtimes.

Comment: Fair enough. I have made the question about google chrome. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: it depends on the API